# Elixir - JasonHelpers - How can I send a keyword list to json_map?

Tags: json, dictionary, elixir

I have a data structure that I want to convert to json and preserve the key order.

For example:
`%{ x: 1, a: 5}` should be converted to `"{\"x\": 1, \"a\": 5}"`

Poison does it without any problem. But when I upgrade to Jason, it changes to `"{\"a\": 5, \"x\": 1}"`.

So I use JasonHelpers json_map to preserve the order like this:

```
Jason.Helpers.json_map([x: 1, a: 5])
```

It creates a fragment with correct order.

However, when I use a variable to do this:

```
list = [x: 1, a: 5]
Jason.Helpers.json_map(list)
```

I have an error:

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for {:list, [line: 15], nil} of type Tuple.
....
```

**QUESTION:** How can I pass a pre-calculated list into `Jason.Helpers.json_map` ?

The calculation is complicated, so I don't want to repeat the code just to use json_map, but use the function that returns a list.

Comment: can you share the complete function, to have more context?

Comment: The context is:
I have a very complex calculation that generate a complex nested structure of data.

I can easily change the code to generate a nested map or a nested keyword list.

Then I want to send that structure as json to client, with the key order in the way I specify, not alphabetical order.

I don't think that the whole function will explain anything better. And obvious reason that I cannot share the whole function is that it is my production code.

Comment: I was reading the documentation about  that and it's a macro, and says `Encodes a JSON map from a compile-time keyword.` and you are creating that keyword-list in runtime

Comment: Doesn't answer your specific question, but if order matters in your client you probably want to restructure it to utilize an array instead of an object. JSON objects are intended to be unordered. You might have an easier time representing your data as `[{"key": "x", "value": 1}, {"key": "a", value: 5}]`.

Comment: @YoelMonzon: Thank you so much. I overlooked it.

Comment: @BrettBeatty: That's not an option, because currently they already have applications that process our json.

I upgraded our application to the current Phoenix, and it upgraded Poison to Jason.
From machine-to-machine standpoint, the order doesn't matter. But we have people who read the data from time to time.

Comment: About JSON object ordering, the spec says this: "The JSON syntax does not […] assign any 
significance to the ordering of name/value pairs. These are […] semantic considerations that may be defined by JSON processors or in specifications defining specific uses of JSON for data interchange." JSON is just a string, so it seems wanting to order the data is a valid concern, even if not advisable because most implementations will deserialise it to an unordered datatype.

Answer (score 5):

[`json_map/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.Helpers.html#json_map/1) is a macro, from its docs:

> Encodes a JSON map from a compile-time keyword.

It is designed for compiling JSON at compile-time, which is why it doesn't work with your runtime variable.

Support for encoding keyword lists was [added to the Jason library a year ago](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason/pull/62), but it looks like it hasn't been pushed to hex yet. I managed to get it work by pulling the latest code from github:

```elixir
defp deps do
  [{:jason, git: "https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason.git"}]
end
```

Then by creating a struct that implements [`Jason.Encoder`](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.Encoder.html) (adapted from [this solution](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason/issues/98#issuecomment-549800939) by the Jason author):

```elixir
defmodule OrderedObject do
  defstruct [:value]

  def new(value), do: %__MODULE__{value: value}

  defimpl Jason.Encoder do
    def encode(%{value: value}, opts) do
      Jason.Encode.keyword(value, opts)
    end
  end
end
```

Now we can encode objects with ordered keys:

```elixir
iex(1)> Jason.encode!(OrderedObject.new([x: 1, a: 5]))
"{\"x\":1,\"a\":5}"
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that the OrderedObject is really good for one level.
I will test it with nested levels, to see if it really work.
For example [x: 1, a: [c: 5, b: 4]]

Comment: I think you will need to create nested `OrderedObject`s if you want to do that. The problem is that there is no way to distinguish between a keyword list and a normal list by datatype alone, so you need to manually add the information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is part of the public API or just an implementation detail, but it appears you have some control of the order when implementing the `Jason.Encoder` protocol for a struct.

Let's say you've defined an `Ordered` struct:

```rb
defmodule Ordered do
  @derive {Jason.Encoder, only: [:a, :x]}
  defstruct [:a, :x]
end
```

If you encode the struct, the "a" key will be before the "x" key:

```rb
iex> Jason.encode!(%Ordered{a: 5, x: 1})
"{\"a\":5,\"x\":1}"
```

Let's reorder the keys we pass in to the `:only` option:

```rb
defmodule Ordered do
  @derive {Jason.Encoder, only: [:x, :a]}
  defstruct [:a, :x]
end
```

If we now encode the struct, the "x" key will be before the "a" key:

```rb
iex> Jason.encode!(%Ordered{a: 5, x: 1})
"{\"x\":1,\"a\":5}"
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew about the @derive solution, but the problem is that I have nested levels of data, so the only must be specified in all of the related modules. 
It should work, but requires some modifications in many modules which I try to avoid.

But if there is nothing that requires less work, this is a good solution.